# BizTalk macro for datetime with 12 digit date

Tags: biztalk

I want the macro to use send port to generate a file with file name Timestamp must be 12 characters in length

eg:  201904060232_testfile.csv 
I tried to us %datetime_bts2000% but it have 15 digit.

can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of all the Send Port Macros. [BizTalk Server: List of Macros](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8823.biztalk-server-list-of-macros.aspx)

Unfortunately there isn't one that matches what you want, but the usual work around is to set the `File.ReceivedFileName` property (either in an Orchestration or using [BRE Pipeline Framework](https://github.com/mbrimble/brepipelineframework)) and use the `%SourceFileName%` macro.